# InvokeScript, JavaScript Error

Tags: c#, jquery, json, browser, invokescript

I have an IE9 Web browser control embedded in a larger WPF application.  I'm attempting to call `InvokeScript` and pass it a JSON string as a parameter:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("redrawPlot", new object[] { reDrawData });
```

The function redrawPlot uses the jquery method `parseJSON` to parse this back into an object:

```
redrawPlot = function(dataObj) {
        dataObj = $.parseJSON(dataObj);
        ...
}
```

When this runs in the WPF app I get the JavaScript error:

```
Invalid character
```

The contents of reDrawData (inspected in script debugger and in the WPF app) are:

> "{\"plot0\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot1\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot2\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot3\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot4\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}]}"

When I run this in under IE9 developer tools passing that string directly I get no errors.

Am I not calling InvokeScript correctly?

Comment: Does the string start with `"` or is that just how the debugger prints it?

Comment: @Musa, are you saying that I would need to add opening/closing `"` to my string to get it passed as a string to the javascript function?

Comment: No I wasn't, but from your question it seems they aren't. Try replacing all `\"` with just `"`.

Comment: @Musa, thanks so much.  You were correct, I had over escaped the string.  If you'd like to re-post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes around you properties and strings are escaped, they should not be. That is

> {\"plot0\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot1\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot2\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot3\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}],\"plot4\":[{\"data\":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],\"label\":\"A-TOP-6\"}]}

should be

> {"plot0":[{"data":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],"label":"A-TOP-6"}],"plot1":[{"data":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],"label":"A-TOP-6"}],"plot2":[{"data":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],"label":"A-TOP-6"}],"plot3":[{"data":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],"label":"A-TOP-6"}],"plot4":[{"data":[[1,1111.11111111111],[2,1111.11111111111],[3,1111.11111111111]],"label":"A-TOP-6"}]}